# How to get a container Div with auto Height and with floating divs inside it?

Tags: html, css-float, css

I have the following HTML

```
<style type="text/css">
<!--
.msg_ok{
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS";
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:10px;
    width:500px;
    height:auto;
    display:block;
}
.msg_ok{
    background-color:#DCFFB9;
    border:#003300 1px solid;
    color:#003500;
}
-->
</style>

      <div class="msg_ok" style="height:auto;">

        <div style="display:block;float:left;width:350px; height:auto;">
          <p>line 1<br>
          line2<br>
          line3<br>
          line4<br>
          line5<br>
          </p>
        </div>
        <div style="display:block;float:left;width:100px; height:auto;">
        <a href="#">Print</a>
        </div>

      </div>
```

And I get this result

[image]

however how i can get a result like the following, the container div with an auto height that fit its size with the floating divs inside?

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

add these

```
.msg_ok{
    overflow:hidden;
    zoom:1;
}
```

and remove `height:auto`, that's useless since height is always auto (by default). the issue you are facing is *how to contain floats*

Comment: See [this page](http://www.positioniseverything.net/easyclearing.html) for details on different methods to contain your floats.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for the clear-fix "hack", to avoid the parent from losing it's height when it contains floating elements, right?

Add a `<div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>` after the last floating div, and then use the following CSS:

```
.clear {
   float: none;
   clear: both;
   height: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an element after the floating elements which clears the floats. Generally:

```
<br style="clear:both" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

[Jsfiddle height auto](http://jsfiddle.net/QvFV8/6/)

Make display property to "inline-block" for msg_ok class

Answer (score 0):

Best method is use clearfix. Refer this link - http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/